# Zimbra: move email to another user

Tags: zimbra

As title says. I need to move all emails in a mailbox to another user. The original user has resigned, and we have assigned his current position to another guy. So I made a folder with the old guy's name at the new guy's inbox, and I need to move all old guy's email to the new guy before I can delete the old guy's account.

But the process is so tedious, and very slow. It is about 25K emails. So I need a more efficient way other than selecting all old mail and drag them to another folder via web interface.

I have tried to close the old email, but then the shared folder couldn't be accessed.

So, is there any more efficient way to move those emails?

Another question: Does dragging those email to another folder run after the browser is closed?

Thank you

Comment: rename the old user mailbox  to the new user?

Comment: the new user already has his mailbox. I am talking in merging two mailboxes, by moving the other emails into a folder.

Comment: then imapsync is the way to go. Test it on the cli and once it's doing what it should run it in cron job or under screen, it'll take long but you do not need to stay watching how it syncs ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If renaming the old user mailbox doesn't work, then you can try `imapsync`.

Comment: Renaming doesn't do any good, since the new guy already has his own mailbox and considerable mails too. And I am actually looking for another option other than imapsync. imapsync is slow, and I don't need any copy.